# Trying to highlight div elements (photos) and retrieving title to pass to an array

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi guys i have the following code which is part of the Twitter's bootstrap's modal. It pulls a user's follower's profile picture from twitter along with their screen name, setting the screen name to the title of the picture.

```
<?php

    $follower_url = http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/Mozammil_K.xml";


    $twFriends = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($twFriends, CURLOPT_URL, $follower_url);
    curl_setopt($twFriends, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $twiFriends = curl_exec($twFriends);
    $response = new SimpleXMLElement($twiFriends);

    foreach($response->user as $friends){ 
    $thumb = $friends->profile_image_url;
    $url = $friends->screen_name;
    $name = $friends->name;

    ?>



    <a title="<?php echo $url;?>" href="#"><img class="photo-img" src="<?php echo $thumb?>" border="0" alt="" width="40" onClick="highlight(this)" /></a>
    <?php
    } 

    ?>

    <script>

        function highlight(element) {





                    }




        </script>



        </div>
```

This produces the following: http://d.pr/i/J6kN

What i am trying to do is, the user can click on the photos which triggers the highlight function. In the highlight function, i should be able to retrieve the photo's title. This is fairly easy with this.title.

What i am also trying to do is, highlight the photos. For e.g, the user clicks on 5 follower's, all of them should be highlighted in a blue border.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use jquery. In the case it ain't possible, you may use this. But mind well, you won't be able to 'unselect' elements...For that, you need something more. And, I would recommend adding a css-class, instead of hard-coding the style over here.

```
function highlight(elem) {
    if(elem.style.border == '1px solid blue') {
        // unselect (remove from array)
        elem.style.border = '';
    }
    else
        elem.style.border = '1px solid blue';
}
```

Comment: Oh, "unselecting" elements should be possible. If the user has wrongly selected an element, it should allow them to unselect and consequently remove the item from the array. Thanks for the help, the highlighting works.

Comment: ohk, so if you click again, the element should be unselected? There's a small addition to code in that case.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will also remove the photo title from the array

Comment: which array? no array here in JS

Comment: I didn't include the array because i know how to do it. I just needed the selecting/unselecting part.

Comment: Thanks! You have been of great help.